# Eclipse: code can't get imported image from package. Code works when read from C:/

Tags: java, eclipse, imageicon

When I try to make an ImageIcon i = new ImageIcon("source"); the code doesn't read it from eclipse package like I want it to but when I tell it to read it from a C:/... file it works.
Why is this and how can I fix it?

Comment: try to clean your project.

Answer (score 4):

`new ImageIcon("source")` is expecting a `File` reference.  Resources maintained within the application are not (normally) considered to be files, instead, they are considered to be, well, resources.

This means you can't access them using the "noraml" approaches you might be used to.

Instead, try using `getClass().getResource("/path/to/resource/source")`

Where the path is the path from the top of your source tree...

Comment: Ok. so now I get an exception;                                                        Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at javax.swing.ImageIcon.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at gameLibrary.Character.<init>(Character.java:15)
 at gameLibrary.ControlPanel.<init>(ControlPanel.java:15)
 at gameLibrary.FrameWork.<init>(FrameWork.java:13)

Comment: So, exactly where is this file your are trying to load, within the context of your project? Is it in the resources folder?